# How to access ForeignKey values in GridView using LinqDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq

The problem is as follows:

I have three tables in database:

ARTICLE with fields like ID_Article, Title, etc. and also a FK ID_Author

CATEGORY with fields ID_Category, Name

CATEGORYTOARTICLE with fields ID_Article, ID_Category

Now I have a page that shows all Articles of a given Category.
Inside there is a GridView.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewCategories" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LinqSourceGridCategories" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Title</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        ???
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>                        
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Plus a LinqDataSource

```
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqSourceGridCategories" runat="server" 
            ContextTypeName="konserwatyzm.db.DataClassesDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
            TableName="CategoryToArticles" Where="ID_Category == @ID_Category">
            <WhereParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID_Category" QueryStringField="id" 
                    Type="Int32" />
            </WhereParameters>
        </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

The ID of the viewed Category is passed via QueryString.

**How to access the fields of Article table so that I can create columns for them in GridView?** I tried using Eval("Article.Title") but it keeps saying that "DataBinding: 'konserwatyzm.db.CategoryToArticle' does not contain a property with the name 'Article'."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have your keys defined correctly in your dbml or map. Then try constructing a query with the linqdatasource configuration wizard by selecting all the tables you want rows for. It looks like you only selected the CategoryToArticles table when you need it + the other two. You'll be able to reference the columns in the other tables that way.

Comment: How can I select several tables in linqdatasource configuration wizard? Is it possible?